# How to read a large error log file without downloading?

Tags: apache, logfile

I need to check my apache error log, but the file contains 14GB of data. Downloading will takes ages. Is there any way how I can see what's in the file without downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you got a SSH access to your server ? In this case this is easy, use a SSH client like putty and read file directly.

If you only got a FTP access, you can try to use Byte range as defined here : http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35

Of course only if your server supports it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have SSH enabled on the server, just remotely login and either **tail** or **grep** the log files.